# Migration to Spring Boot (Security) 2 from 1.x

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

In a current migration of a project from Spring boot 1.X to 2.0.9 I am facing a hard time with the Spring Security module. In a first step I have to change the properties to access the datasources (to jdbc-url) and now that part seems to be working just fine, but now the security module seems to be not rightly attached.

So in properties I have tried to add the following:
`spring.security.user.name=admin`
`spring.security.user.password=secret`
But even if I comment it or dis-comment it, I face the same result, when I call the webservices, the dialog prompts asking for credentials:

[image]
The configuration of the authentication is the following:

```
class OAuth2Configuration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer // [1]
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    @EnableWebSecurity
    protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Autowired
        private DataSource oauthDataSource;

        @Autowired
        private PhrqlAuthenticationManager phrqlAuthenticationManager;


        /**
         * Config clientDetail storage
         * @param endpoints
         * @throws Exception
         */
        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(phrqlAuthenticationManager);
            endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore);
            //          endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).pathMapping("/oauth/token", "/p/oauth/token");

        }


        @Override // [3]
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.jdbc(oauthDataSource);
        } 

    }
```

For some reason, I think that the autoconfig is not accessing to the name-pass, so then the client ask for credentials. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!